# Generate random ids for tables that is inside a foreach loop in a view with MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Im using MVC-Viewmodel, EF Model first on my project.

I have a foreach loop that generates 4 tables inside my view. I want that each table that generates gets an unique ID. I guess that I have to do this inside my ViewModel.

Any kind help is appreciated All I know is that I need to declare something like this inside my foreach loop:

```
<table id="RandomID_@("MyRandomProperty)">
```

and probably a property like this:

```
public random MyRandomProperty {get;set;}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does raise the question...why?

Comment: Why don't you just increment a counter?  Trying to generate a random id will result you getting the same key multiple times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a Guid:

```
<table id="RandomID_@(Guid.NewGuid())">
```

Answer (score 4):

How about using a GUID as your ID property?

```
private Guid _tableId;
public Guid TableId = {
    get {
        if(_tableId == null)
            _tableId = Guid.NewGuid();

         return _tableId;
     }
 }
```

Or you could just call `Guid.NewGuid()` inline in your View?  Dependes if you need to access the ID from else where in your code...

Hope this helps,

James